# .bashrc doesn't exist and doesn't work

Tags: release-loki, system, pantheon-terminal, bash

There was no .bashrc or .bash_profile in my home folder.
I created a new file and put inside my aliases. They don't work, terminal ignores everything.
Why?

Answer (score 1):

There must be some configuration issues, as there is a `.bashrc` and a `.profile` file in a default user home directory.

You can check the default settings files in `/etc/skel`.

Or you might want to create a new test user to play around with settings, hack together a `.bashrc` and a `.profile` files and copy them to your user home once it works as you want it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Below there is a link which contains a source.

[git bashrc source](https://gist.github.com/kossoy/f87acbdc5b14e06bb20a2da645666637)